# Way of finding out all different versions of a word

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is related to programming as that is what inspired the question. However, the concept itself is mathematical.

Given a series of upper or lowercase letters, is there a way of finding out all the different combinations that could be created from those letters? For example, if given $a,b,c,d,e$ as letters and a maximum length of 3 letters, a list of valid combinations would be:

$$a,b,c,d,e,aa,ab,...,ed,ee,aaa,...,eee$$

Likewise, the letters $a,b$ and a maximum word length $2$ would result in $a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb$ ($6$). I am aware of $nCr$ and $nPr$ but neither $2P2$ or $2C2$ result in $6$, so they do not seem to work.

Is there a method that would result in the correct answer for any number of letters and any maximum word length, rather than listing each one out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is the number of letters and $n$ is the maximum word length, the number of possible words $w(k,n)$ equals:

$$w(k,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n k^i = \frac{k(k^n-1)}{k-1}$$

Using this equation, we find $w(5,3) = 155$ and $w(2,2) = 6$.